# Sharepoint 2010: JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type SP.EnumerableArray has already been registered

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-online

Environment: 
Sharepoint 2010 with Service Pack 2
.NET Framework 3.5
Windows: Windows 2008 R2
Visual Studio 2010

I am getting this error when I run the event receiver in the debugging mode and moved from one list item to another in SharePoint.

> JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type SP.EnumerableArray has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.

FYI: I have not written any code in event receiver. Event Receiver created using farm solutions and deployed using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: reason you might have this error is that you have some script files referenced more than once on page.

Comment: would you share your code please

Comment: For your information, i have no code in event receiver.

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {

base.ItemUpdated(properties);
       }

Comment: And also we are not adding any script file in our program.

Comment: Hi Niranjan, Please let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Try setting compilation debug=false in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the script references in your page. There might be multiple references to the same file causing this issue.